# How to Calculate students Rank based on the Total, If the Total amount repeated twice then the rank should be same

Tags: c#, asp.net, ranking

Here what I tried :

```
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
  dt.DefaultView.Sort = "ratio DESC";
  dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Rank", typeof(int)));
  int count = 1;

  foreach (DataRowView dr in dt.DefaultView)
    {
      dr["Rank"] = count++;
    }
```

While I am looping it should check some condition, can any one help me ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Consider adding a reproducible example

Comment: @mybirthname Thanks for your reply, Here i having set of students record in data table , I like to calculate the Rank for the Students, based on the total. I used "desc" for  my datatable to descending the amount coloumn  to get higher amount in the top row. then i looping the records to generate rank. Here my problem is "If the total amount exist twice, then both total records should be same"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to access previous row value while looping. Go with traditional for loop. Be careful for the first record as there will be previous row for it.

```
for( int i = 0; i < dt.DefaultView.Rows.Count; i++ )
{
    if( i > 0 )
    {
       // Compare with previous row using index
       if( dt.DefaultView.Rows[i]["ratio"] == dt.DefaultView.Rows[i-1]["ratio"])
       {
           dt.DefaultView.Rows[i]["Rank"] = count;
       }
      else
      {
          dt.DefaultView.Rows[i]["Rank"] = count++;
      }
    }
   else
   {
       dt.DefaultView.Rows[i]["Rank"] = count;
   } 

}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. This is the one what am searching and thinking... thanks a lot

Comment: WC :). Plz mark it tick and upvote, this is how we say thanks in SO.